# Visualizing features and activations in CNN using Keras example

Tags: deep-learning, keras, feature-selection, activation

I'm following the keras blog post code to visualize the features learned and activations at different layers. The code has randomly generated a gray-image of dimension (1,3,img_width, img_height) and visualized it. here it is:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from scipy.misc import imsave
import numpy as np
import time
from keras.applications import vgg16
from keras import backend as K

# dimensions of the generated pictures for each filter.
img_width = 128
img_height = 128

# the name of the layer we want to visualize
# (see model definition at keras/applications/vgg16.py)
layer_name = 'block5_conv1'

# util function to convert a tensor into a valid image


def deprocess_image(x):
    # normalize tensor: center on 0., ensure std is 0.1
    x -= x.mean()
    x /= (x.std() + 1e-5)
    x *= 0.1

    # clip to [0, 1]
    x += 0.5
    x = np.clip(x, 0, 1)

    # convert to RGB array
    x *= 255
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        x = x.transpose((1, 2, 0))
    x = np.clip(x, 0, 255).astype('uint8')
    return x

# build the VGG16 network with ImageNet weights
model = vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
print('Model loaded.')

model.summary()

# this is the placeholder for the input images
input_img = model.input

# get the symbolic outputs of each "key" layer (we gave them unique names).
layer_dict = dict([(layer.name, layer) for layer in model.layers[1:]])


def normalize(x):
    # utility function to normalize a tensor by its L2 norm
    return x / (K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(x))) + 1e-5)


kept_filters = []
for filter_index in range(0, 200):
    # we only scan through the first 200 filters,
    # but there are actually 512 of them
    print('Processing filter %d' % filter_index)
    start_time = time.time()

    # we build a loss function that maximizes the activation
    # of the nth filter of the layer considered
    layer_output = layer_dict[layer_name].output
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        loss = K.mean(layer_output[:, filter_index, :, :])
    else:
        loss = K.mean(layer_output[:, :, :, filter_index])

    # we compute the gradient of the input picture wrt this loss
    grads = K.gradients(loss, input_img)[0]

    # normalization trick: we normalize the gradient
    grads = normalize(grads)

    # this function returns the loss and grads given the input picture
    iterate = K.function([input_img], [loss, grads])

    # step size for gradient ascent
    step = 1.

    # we start from a gray image with some random noise
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        input_img_data = np.random.random((1, 3, img_width, img_height))
    else:
        input_img_data = np.random.random((1, img_width, img_height, 3))
    input_img_data = (input_img_data - 0.5) * 20 + 128

    # we run gradient ascent for 20 steps
    for i in range(20):
        loss_value, grads_value = iterate([input_img_data])
        input_img_data += grads_value * step

        print('Current loss value:', loss_value)
        if loss_value <= 0.:
            # some filters get stuck to 0, we can skip them
            break

    # decode the resulting input image
    if loss_value > 0:
        img = deprocess_image(input_img_data[0])
        kept_filters.append((img, loss_value))
    end_time = time.time()
    print('Filter %d processed in %ds' % (filter_index, end_time - start_time))

# we will stich the best 64 filters on a 8 x 8 grid.
n = 8

# the filters that have the highest loss are assumed to be better-looking.
# we will only keep the top 64 filters.
kept_filters.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
kept_filters = kept_filters[:n * n]

# build a black picture with enough space for
# our 8 x 8 filters of size 128 x 128, with a 5px margin in between
margin = 5
width = n * img_width + (n - 1) * margin
height = n * img_height + (n - 1) * margin
stitched_filters = np.zeros((width, height, 3))

# fill the picture with our saved filters
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        img, loss = kept_filters[i * n + j]
        stitched_filters[(img_width + margin) * i: (img_width + margin) * i + img_width,
                         (img_height + margin) * j: (img_height + margin) * j + img_height, :] = img

# save the result to disk
imsave('stitched_filters_%dx%d.png' % (n, n), stitched_filters)
```

Could you please let me know how can I modify these statements in the code:

```
input_img_data = np.random.random((1, img_width, img_height, 3))
        input_img_data = (input_img_data - 0.5) * 20 + 128
```

to insert my own data and visualize the features learned and activations? My image is a RGB image of dimensions 150, 150. thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to process single image:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img

img = load_img('data/XXXX.jpg')  # this is a PIL image
x = img_to_array(img) 
x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)
```

If you want to process batch:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
data_gen_args = dict(featurewise_center=True,
                 featurewise_std_normalization=True,
                 rotation_range=90.,
                 width_shift_range=0.1,
                 height_shift_range=0.1,
                 zoom_range=0.2)
image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)


image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/images',
    class_mode=None,
    seed=seed)
```

To see documentation : https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator

## Update

```
# we start from a gray image with some random noise
if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    img = load_img('images/1/1.png')  # this is a PIL image
    x = img_to_array(img)
    x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)
else:
    #input_img_data = np.random.random((1, img_width, img_height, 3))
    img = load_img('images/1/1.png')  # this is a PIL image
    x = img_to_array(img)
    x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)
input_img_data = x
input_img_data = (input_img_data - 0.5) * 20 + 128
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that. I'm having issues with reshaping the image after I load it. Kindly let me know how should I modify these statements to fit my image into the model:                                                                         if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        input_img_data = np.random.random((1, 3, img_width, img_height))
    else:
        input_img_data = np.random.random((1, img_width, img_height, 3))
    input_img_data = (input_img_data - 0.5) * 20 + 128

Comment: @shiva, see the update. Replace that piece of code with this. Add import line as well. Its working for me.

Comment: @shiva, is it working for you ? If so, could you accept/vote the answer so that question gets closed. Thanks

Comment: Hi,its not working for me. Am using a grayscale image of dimensions 128 * 128 in .jpg format. when i run the program, i get this error at this point:                                           img, loss = kept_filters[i * n + j]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @shiva, Hi code mentioned above works for RGB. Try with RGB image. Later, convert RGB channels (3) to 1 in your code. Your previous code deals with RGB channels and its working pretty well on my machine.